# Reduced model size by almost 3.5 times. Now I am never able to cycles render in Optix

Tags: memory-management

I had a (bloated) model having 3.6 million tringles (just for example) that I was able to render it in cycles (barely, no other apps, just booted) on a RTX 3070 TI (8GB). Now, I have reduced it to 1 million triangles, half a million edges and so on, by working an practically all objects in it and now I am never able to render it. How is that possible?
Simplify is enabled (but appears to have absolutely no effect). I now peaks at 8.3G. Before I started to reducing it, it peaked at just below 6G. what is really going on?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question but desperate time, desperate measures. I saw that my render window (F12) stop a good while loading a texture from BlenderKit, "car pain white rough" or something like that. I listed all instances of it and there was about 8 or them. Removed all and now it renders in cycles about HALF the VRAM requirement, 4.1G peak. Hope this help somebody.
Btw, I tried different version of Blender and the VRAM use was about the same.

Comment: Hi, glad you found a solution. It's okay to answer your own question. After a "cooling down" period of about 2 days, you even can accept your answer to show that the question is solved.